# Twitter Media Could Not Be Played on Laptop Browsers

Tags: twitter

Using **Chrome** (Version 91.0.4472.124 (Official Build) (64-bit)) , **Firefox** 89.0.2 (64-bit), and **Microsoft Edge** 91.0.864.67 (Official build) (64-bit)
I am not able to see any **Twitter** (Only Twitter) videos on my laptop browser and after spinning loader icon for while I am getting "`The Media Could not be played`" error message.

This was working properly since this morning but now I am getting this! I already cleared all browser data but still getting this issue

[image]

Can u pls let me know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using a proxy or a VPN?  [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound, Hi Ramhound, you are right. after disabling VPN the twitter is working properly now. Thanks

Comment: I truly meant no offense so I am sorry if it came across that way.  You have but one tag of `twitter` .. for all I know you are using an iPad with a keyboard and calling it a laptop.  I seriously had no idea what you were talking about.  Please forgive me.

Comment: Oh.. and I am very glad that your issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests a hardware, or at least firmware, issue. Try turning off hardware acceleration in your browsers. This has been known to fix video issues in the past.

If this is a different type of issue, then one thing to try would be checking for any errors in your browser's console (press <kbd>F12</kbd>) when you try to load these videos.

Answer (score 0):

Having same issue under **Firefox** (117.0.1), but currently works fine under **Edge**  (116.0.1938.81).
[Test page](https://twitter.com/ThisIsEng/status/1034694682586935302).